# Import CSS file into Javascript file or link to HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just joined a project and noticed that the stylesheet is imported into each page's JS file as such:

`import "../../style.css";`

Now, I'm used to seeing CSS stylesheets linked in HTML files as follows:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

The project is using Javascript/jQuery and Vite.js as an alternative to Webpack. I looked at the Vite documentation and saw that the example projects use the CSS @import, but there's no information on why that is in particular.

Is there any reason to import the stylesheet into JS files, rather than linking to the HTML files? Or vice versa? Not looking for opinions here, I'm wondering if there are best practices or advantages/disadvantages to consider with one approach or another.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's an opinion based question. It really depends on the project and how it was set up.

Comment: @disinfor - I'm not sure I agree-- just because it is context-dependent doesn't mean that it is entirely opinion-based, no?  The user is in good faith asking the difference between these two approaches.

Comment: @disinfor Ok...your answer doesn't really provide any useful information. I'm just trying to gain a better understanding here in regards to best practices, advantages/disadvantages of one approach or another.

Comment: @AlexanderNied sure, but based on the last comment, I think we're looking at an open ended question.

Comment: @MickeyVershbow I didn't answer your question. I made a comment to why this might not be a good question. However, if there are answers that meet your requirements, even better.

Comment: It's a comment. Because the question is too open ended.

Comment: @disinfor so do you have any suggestions as to how to make this question less open-ended? What is the point of your comments here?

Comment: @isherwood, thanks, I was unaware that would be useful in context of this question. I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

It hands off the decision about when to include different bits of CSS to the bundler (e.g. webpack) instead of including every bit of CSS everywhere.

Further reading: [Tree shaking CSS Modules](https://markmurray.co/blog/tree-shaking-css-modules/)